# Server Update Process Design Patterns

Tags: java, networking, netty

I've been searching around stackoverflow for similar questions, such as MMORPG server
design patterns and such, since the concept is essentially the same, however, I've came
to no satisfactory conclusion for solving my problem.

**Functionality**
Essentially, the server software (which is being developed in Java using JBoss Netty) simply
allows authenticated appliance clients to transmit and control entity data, which is then transmitted to device clients which are specified range.

**Considered Approaches**
1. Use a fixed thread pool, and queue device updates periodically, in which the server 
   performs a check for entities within range of the device, and the transmits appropriate
   spawn/update/destroy packets.
2. Use a rector style model, where events are posted to the reactor and processed
   synchronously. An event, for example, could be posted when an appliance updates 
   an entity or a device updates it's location. The server could then select entities in 
   range of the device and transmit the appropriate create/update/destroy packets
   asynchronously.
3. Perform the updates on the Netty event thread. For example, the client updates it's
   location, the server performs a check for entities within range and sends the appropriate
   create/update/destroy packets. The problem is that with this approach, the server will
   not transmit entities unless the device updates it's location. A means to resolve that
   issue might also be to select devices in range upon an entity create/update/destroy 
   message from the appliance and update each one synchronously.

These are just a few approaches I've considered, I'm looking for the most scalable approach 
providing the least possible latency, as the data needs to be as real-time as possible. 
Any other recommended approaches are welcome.

My apologies if my question lacks sufficient information, I'll gladly correct any mistakes
or provide additional information as requested.

Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [multiplayer netty game server](https://github.com/menacher/java-game-server) I have written. You may find some answers to your q there. I am yet undecided on the scalability part. I am looking at multiple options here.

1. Do not share state across multiple vm's. This means that players will get lowest latency. Downside is that they will not be able to jump from one vm to another if their peers are playing there. In this model, incoming events will be stored/journaled and in case of a crash etc, they will be replayed for sake of durability. Something like the following [chronicle](https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Chronicle) would help.
2. Share state between vm's. Latency may take a hit but scalability will definitely be higher. I am looking at [hazelcast](http://www.hazelcast.com/). Which allows transparent state sharing to happen.

Comment: I actually downloaded a copy of your source while researching it, and it appear to me that you are performing your update on the Netty I/O thread (i.e messageReceived), by looking at the example game server. Is that correct?

Comment: No. If you look at the DefaultToServerHandler class in handlers.netty package you will see playerSession.onEvent(event). This call is actually async since the Sessions EventDispatcher(you can see 2 event dispatchers in event.impl package) will dispatch it to a different thread. Also checkout the JetlangEventDispatcherTest class in src/test. The PlayerSession*Test will also show how async event dispatch is done.

Comment: Thank you for the explaination :) After reviewing it, I understand it now. I'm thinking that I'll process I/O events (such as spawn/update/destroy) one at a time on a single thread pool, followed by client transmit logic (which will be executed in parallel on a fixed or cached thread pool).
Also, thanks for all your responses.